# iPhone UISlider crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider, exc-bad-access

I have an UISlider that shows the progress of a song, and the user can go back and forth using it.

I'm using a custom player an the code for my UISlider is the following:

```
mySlider.value = (float)myAudio.packetPosition  / (float)myAudio.totalTimeInBytes;
```

All works perfectly but sometimes the application crashes, receiving a EXC_BAD_ACESS. Maybe it's a division by zero, I don't know.

How do I prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just check if `totalTimeInBytes` is equal to zero?

Comment: I tried that, but with no avail.

Comment: post the crash log. EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are referencing a deallocated object, not division by zero.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACESS` could mean that you are trying to call a method on a object which is no longer in memory, try enabling [`NSZombies`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).

Comment: It's a bug hard to reproduce, but I'll enable NSZombie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!(myAudio.totalTimeInBytes == 0.0f))
{
     mySlider.value = (float)myAudio.packetPosition  / (float)myAudio.totalTimeInBytes;
}
else
{
    mySlider.value = 0.0f; 
}
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know the results. Thank you!